# Magento - iOS Browser cannot upload file - Error message when proceeding to shopping cart

Tags: java, php, ios, magento, attributes

On this page https://www.logobox24.com/individuelle-schachtel.html#132=3 we have a form with the possibility to upload a picture/file. With desktop browsers it works fine. But when using an iPad/iPhone I can upload the file but when proceeding the process to the shopping cart it does not work - sometimes there is an error message that article options have to be selected and the user is not forwarded to the shopping cart at all. Sometimes the user is forwarded to the shopping cart but the uploaded picture/file is missing in the shopping cart. Any knows how to solve this problem? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Really hard to debug especially when it only happens *sometimes*. I suspect some problems when the mobile connection is not proper.

As long as you don't have any concrete points to reliably reproduce it again and again and some code samples as well this might be not the right place to ask.
Nobody he can look into your code and tell your what's wrong.

Comment: New Info: When I tried to upload files with the iPad/iPhone I always choose quite big pictures I had on the device. I then tried it with a small picture and it suddenly worked. So the file size seems to be the problem. I then tried bigger files on the PC and I also get the problem. How can I solve this filesize issue? Thx

Comment: How big are your pictures? Any chance you can upload one of them somewhere so I can try?

Comment: Just try any picture or pdf with 20 MB

Comment: I was now able to increase the upload file size to 64MB and this works fine on desktop browsers. But on iPad/iPhone I can still just upload very tiny images/files. Any idea how tonsolve that?